# rqt_graph topic statistics not working

Tags: ros, rqt-graph, ros-indigo

[image: Rosanswers logo]

This is the documentation i'm following:

http://wiki.ros.org/rqt_graph#Topic_statistics

This feature is not working on my system. I can't find the reason why.

- ROS Indigo
- Ubuntu 14.04

Tested by creating some instances of the turtlesim package's executables.

Here's my result when using rqt_graph. You can see from the terminal window that the parameter is currently set to ***true***

Image:

[image: https://i.imgur.com/U3y98es.png]

Please ignore the line under the terminal window.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/188315/rqt_graph-topic-statistics-not-working/) by [dotcom](https://answers.ros.org/users/19883/dotcom/) on ROS Answers with karma: 120 on 2014-07-30

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [dotcom](https://answers.ros.org/users/19883/dotcom/) on 2014-07-31**:
As answered below, besides setting the parameter to true, one needs to launch topic monitor and *tick* every statistics that is desired.

1. Launch rqt
2. Plugins -> topics -> topic monitor

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

You may need to set the parameter before launching the nodes you want to introspect. I am able to monitor the statistics between turtlesim and the robot steering rqt plugin on my machine running indigo:

[image: image description]

Also, remember that you need to manually refresh the rqt Node Graph window using the refresh button.

---

Originally posted by [William](https://answers.ros.org/users/10/william/) with karma: 17335 on 2014-07-30

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [dotcom](https://answers.ros.org/users/19883/dotcom/) on 2014-07-31**:
Thank you, I think I was missing the ticks on Topic Monitor. The rqt_graph documentation led me to believe all statistics measurements would be active after setting the parameter to true. Enabling isn't the same as doing that, though.